# Is there an accurate curve fitting method that returns coefficients which can be used to generate the original curve back via a function? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, curve

1. Take a set of data and plot a curve.
2. Take the curve and apply curve fitting to generate coefficients.
3. Use coefficients to generate the curve back via a function.

Currently tried polynomial with nth orders, but is very inaccurate. Also tried spline which is accurate but does not allow the curve to be regenerated only using a function.

Comment: There are many regression techniques that can be applied in matlab either manually or with built in functions. High order polynomial regression is a powerful tool. To me your methods are suspect because a high enough order polynomial should be able to regress most curves at least within the range of data provided.... You have not shown any attempts so we can't see if you've done it correctly.

Comment: A spline *is* a function. It just happens that the parameters to the function encode all the values in the input set of data. The existence of a lower-order function that can satisfy your criteria for accuracy is entirely dependent on your data and the processes that generated it. There is no general solution for this problem; your question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for a spline fit & method. MATLAB spline objects do allow a curve to be regenerated using only a function (`ppval`). 
e.g.

```
% original curve 1
x = linspace(0, 4);
y = cos(2 * pi * x);
subplot 221
plot(x, y)
title('Original Curve 2')

% fitted curve 1
p = pchip(x, y);
s = spline(x, y);
subplot 223
plot(x, ppval(p, x), x, ppval(s, x))
legend('pchip','spline')
title('Fitted Curve 1')

% original curve 2
nSample = 1001;
x = linspace(0, 1e-2, nSample);
nPulse = 9;
c = [linspace(0.001, 0.009, nPulse); (7/8).^(1:nPulse)]';
y = pulstran(x, c, @gauspuls, 10000, 0.5); 
subplot 222
plot(x, y)
title('Original Curve 2')

% fitted curve 2
p = pchip(x, y);
s = spline(x, y);
subplot 224
plot(x, ppval(p, x), x, ppval(s, x))
legend('pchip','spline')
title('Fitted Curve 2')
```

Comment: That's perfect, tyvm :D.